# javascript and django chat app with voice recording

Tags: javascript, django-models, django-views, django-templates

> trying to make a voice recording using django and ajax to submit it.
> the code is here

> below is the index.html for now it allow the recording and then immediately play back the record to confirm that everything is working fine
> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Audio Recording Demo</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Audio Recording API Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="audio-recording-container">
        <div class="main-audio">
            <h1 class="title">Audio Recording API Demo</h1>
            <i class="start-recording-button fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div class="recording-contorl-buttons-container hide">
                <i class="cancel-recording-button fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="recording-elapsed-time">
                    <i class="red-recording-dot fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p class="elapsed-time"></p>
                </div>
                <i class="stop-recording-button fa fa-stop-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="text-indication-of-audio-playing-container">
                <p class="text-indication-of-audio-playing hide">Audio is playing<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay hide">
        <div class="browser-not-supporting-audio-recording-box">
            <p>To record audio, use browsers like Chrome and Firefox that support audio recording.</p>
            <button type="button" class="close-browser-not-supported-box">Ok.</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <audio controls class="audio-element hide">
    </audio>

    <script src="js/audio-recording.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
/* style.css*/

/* Media Queries */

/* Small Devices*/

@media (min-width: 0px) {
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #667eea;
        color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 55px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .audio-recording-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        /* view port height*/
        /*targeting Chrome & Safari*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /*targeting IE10*/
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        /*horizontal centering*/
        align-items: center;
    }
    .main-audio{
        width: 700px;
        height: 200px;
        /* view port height*/
        /*targeting Chrome & Safari*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /*targeting IE10*/
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        /*horizontal centering*/
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #6c69cd;
    }
    .start-recording-button {
        font-size: 70px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: .5;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .start-recording-button:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .recording-contorl-buttons-container {
        /*targeting Chrome & Safari*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /*targeting IE10*/
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        /*horizontal centering*/
        align-items: center;
        width: 334px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .cancel-recording-button,
    .stop-recording-button {
        font-size: 70px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .cancel-recording-button {
        color: red;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    .cancel-recording-button:hover {
        color: rgb(206, 4, 4);
    }
    .stop-recording-button {
        color: #33cc33;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    .stop-recording-button:hover {
        color: #27a527;
    }
    .recording-elapsed-time {
        /*targeting Chrome & Safari*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /*targeting IE10*/
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        /*horizontal centering*/
        align-items: center;
    }
    .red-recording-dot {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: red;
        margin-right: 12px;
        /*transitions with Firefox, IE and Opera Support browser support*/
        animation-name: flashing-recording-dot;
        -webkit-animation-name: flashing-recording-dot;
        -moz-animation-name: flashing-recording-dot;
        -o-animation-name: flashing-recording-dot;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
        -o-animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    /* The animation code */
    @keyframes flashing-recording-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes flashing-recording-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes flashing-recording-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes flashing-recording-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    .elapsed-time {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
    .recording-contorl-buttons-container.hide {
        display: none;
    }
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(82, 76, 76, 0.35);
        /*targeting Chrome & Safari*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /*targeting IE10*/
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        /*horizontal centering*/
        align-items: center;
    }
    .overlay.hide {
        display: none;
    }
    .browser-not-supporting-audio-recording-box {
        /*targeting Chrome & Safari*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /*targeting IE10*/
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        /*horizontal centering*/
        align-items: center;
        width: 317px;
        height: 119px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .close-browser-not-supported-box {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #abc1c05c;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
    }
    .close-browser-not-supported-box:hover {
        background-color: #92a5a45c;
    }
    .close-browser-not-supported-box:focus {
        outline: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .audio-element.hide {
        display: none;
    }
    .text-indication-of-audio-playing-container {
        height: 20px;
    }
    .text-indication-of-audio-playing {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .text-indication-of-audio-playing.hide {
        display: none;
    }
    /* 3 Dots animation*/
    .text-indication-of-audio-playing span {
        /*transitions with Firefox, IE and Opera Support browser support*/
        animation-name: blinking-dot;
        -webkit-animation-name: blinking-dot;
        -moz-animation-name: blinking-dot;
        -o-animation-name: blinking-dot;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
        -o-animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .text-indication-of-audio-playing span:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: .4s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
        -moz-animation-delay: .4s;
        -o-animation-delay: .4s;
    }
    .text-indication-of-audio-playing span:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: .8s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: .8s;
        -moz-animation-delay: .8s;
        -o-animation-delay: .8s;
    }
    /* The animation code */
    @keyframes blinking-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    /* The animation code */
    @-webkit-keyframes blinking-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    /* The animation code */
    @-moz-keyframes blinking-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    /* The animation code */
    @-o-keyframes blinking-dot {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
}

/* Medium devices */

@media (min-width: 768px) {}

/* Large devices */

@media (min-width: 992px) {}

/*Ipad pro view*/

/* 
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
  
  } */

/* Extra Large devices */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

script.js

```
// index.js ---------------
//Model 
//none

//View
var microphoneButton = document.getElementsByClassName("start-recording-button")[0];
var recordingControlButtonsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("recording-contorl-buttons-container")[0];
var stopRecordingButton = document.getElementsByClassName("stop-recording-button")[0];
var cancelRecordingButton = document.getElementsByClassName("cancel-recording-button")[0];
var elapsedTimeTag = document.getElementsByClassName("elapsed-time")[0];
var closeBrowserNotSupportedBoxButton = document.getElementsByClassName("close-browser-not-supported-box")[0];
var overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0];
var audioElement = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0];
var audioElementSource = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0]
    .getElementsByTagName("source")[0];
var textIndicatorOfAudiPlaying = document.getElementsByClassName("text-indication-of-audio-playing")[0];

//Listeners

//Listen to start recording button
microphoneButton.onclick = startAudioRecording;

//Listen to stop recording button
stopRecordingButton.onclick = stopAudioRecording;

//Listen to cancel recording button
cancelRecordingButton.onclick = cancelAudioRecording;

//Listen to when the ok button is clicked in the browser not supporting audio recording box
closeBrowserNotSupportedBoxButton.onclick = hideBrowserNotSupportedOverlay;

//Listen to when the audio being played ends
audioElement.onended = hideTextIndicatorOfAudioPlaying;

/** Displays recording control buttons */
function handleDisplayingRecordingControlButtons() {
    //Hide the microphone button that starts audio recording
    microphoneButton.style.display = "none";

    //Display the recording control buttons
    recordingControlButtonsContainer.classList.remove("hide");

    //Handle the displaying of the elapsed recording time
    handleElapsedRecordingTime();
}

/** Hide the displayed recording control buttons */
function handleHidingRecordingControlButtons() {
    //Display the microphone button that starts audio recording
    microphoneButton.style.display = "block";

    //Hide the recording control buttons
    recordingControlButtonsContainer.classList.add("hide");

    //stop interval that handles both time elapsed and the red dot
    clearInterval(elapsedTimeTimer);
}

/** Displays browser not supported info box for the user*/
function displayBrowserNotSupportedOverlay() {
    overlay.classList.remove("hide");
}

/** Displays browser not supported info box for the user*/
function hideBrowserNotSupportedOverlay() {
    overlay.classList.add("hide");
}

/** Creates a source element for the the audio element in the HTML document*/
function createSourceForAudioElement() {
    let sourceElement = document.createElement("source");
    audioElement.appendChild(sourceElement);

    audioElementSource = sourceElement;
}

/** Display the text indicator of the audio being playing in the background */
function displayTextIndicatorOfAudioPlaying() {
    textIndicatorOfAudiPlaying.classList.remove("hide");
}

/** Hide the text indicator of the audio being playing in the background */
function hideTextIndicatorOfAudioPlaying() {
    textIndicatorOfAudiPlaying.classList.add("hide");
}

//Controller

/** Stores the actual start time when an audio recording begins to take place to ensure elapsed time start time is accurate*/
var audioRecordStartTime;

/** Stores the maximum recording time in hours to stop recording once maximum recording hour has been reached */
var maximumRecordingTimeInHours = 1;

/** Stores the reference of the setInterval function that controls the timer in audio recording*/
var elapsedTimeTimer;

/** Starts the audio recording*/
function startAudioRecording() {

    console.log("Recording Audio...");

    //If a previous audio recording is playing, pause it
    let recorderAudioIsPlaying = !audioElement.paused; // the paused property tells whether the media element is paused or not
    console.log("paused?", !recorderAudioIsPlaying);
    if (recorderAudioIsPlaying) {
        audioElement.pause();
        //also hide the audio playing indicator displayed on the screen
        hideTextIndicatorOfAudioPlaying();
    }

    //start recording using the audio recording API
    audioRecorder.start()
        .then(() => { //on success

            //store the recording start time to display the elapsed time according to it
            audioRecordStartTime = new Date();

            //display control buttons to offer the functionality of stop and cancel
            handleDisplayingRecordingControlButtons();
        })
        .catch(error => { //on error
            //No Browser Support Error
            if (error.message.includes("mediaDevices API or getUserMedia method is not supported in this browser.")) {
                console.log("To record audio, use browsers like Chrome and Firefox.");
                displayBrowserNotSupportedOverlay();
            }

            //Error handling structure
            switch (error.name) {
                case 'AbortError': //error from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
                    console.log("An AbortError has occured.");
                    break;
                case 'NotAllowedError': //error from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
                    console.log("A NotAllowedError has occured. User might have denied permission.");
                    break;
                case 'NotFoundError': //error from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
                    console.log("A NotFoundError has occured.");
                    break;
                case 'NotReadableError': //error from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
                    console.log("A NotReadableError has occured.");
                    break;
                case 'SecurityError': //error from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia or from the MediaRecorder.start
                    console.log("A SecurityError has occured.");
                    break;
                case 'TypeError': //error from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
                    console.log("A TypeError has occured.");
                    break;
                case 'InvalidStateError': //error from the MediaRecorder.start
                    console.log("An InvalidStateError has occured.");
                    break;
                case 'UnknownError': //error from the MediaRecorder.start
                    console.log("An UnknownError has occured.");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("An error occured with the error name " + error.name);
            };
        });
}
/** Stop the currently started audio recording & sends it
 */
function stopAudioRecording() {

    console.log("Stopping Audio Recording...");

    //stop the recording using the audio recording API
    audioRecorder.stop()
        .then(audioAsblob => {
            //Play recorder audio
            playAudio(audioAsblob);

            //hide recording control button & return record icon
            handleHidingRecordingControlButtons();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //Error handling structure
            switch (error.name) {
                case 'InvalidStateError': //error from the MediaRecorder.stop
                    console.log("An InvalidStateError has occured.");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("An error occured with the error name " + error.name);
            };
        });
}

/** Cancel the currently started audio recording */
function cancelAudioRecording() {
    console.log("Canceling audio...");

    //cancel the recording using the audio recording API
    audioRecorder.cancel();

    //hide recording control button & return record icon
    handleHidingRecordingControlButtons();
}

/** Plays recorded audio using the audio element in the HTML document
 * @param {Blob} recorderAudioAsBlob - recorded audio as a Blob Object 
*/
function playAudio(recorderAudioAsBlob) {

    //read content of files (Blobs) asynchronously
    let reader = new FileReader();

    //once content has been read
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        //store the base64 URL that represents the URL of the recording audio
        let base64URL = e.target.result;

        //If this is the first audio playing, create a source element
        //as pre populating the HTML with a source of empty src causes error
        if (!audioElementSource) //if its not defined create it (happens first time only)
            createSourceForAudioElement();

        //set the audio element's source using the base64 URL
        audioElementSource.src = base64URL;

        //set the type of the audio element based on the recorded audio's Blob type
        let BlobType = recorderAudioAsBlob.type.includes(";") ?
            recorderAudioAsBlob.type.substr(0, recorderAudioAsBlob.type.indexOf(';')) : recorderAudioAsBlob.type;
        audioElementSource.type = BlobType

        //call the load method as it is used to update the audio element after changing the source or other settings
        audioElement.load();

        //play the audio after successfully setting new src and type that corresponds to the recorded audio
        console.log("Playing audio...");
        audioElement.play();

        //Display text indicator of having the audio play in the background
        displayTextIndicatorOfAudioPlaying();
    };

    //read content and convert it to a URL (base64)
    reader.readAsDataURL(recorderAudioAsBlob);
}

/** Computes the elapsed recording time since the moment the function is called in the format h:m:s*/
function handleElapsedRecordingTime() {
    //display inital time when recording begins
    displayElapsedTimeDuringAudioRecording("00:00");

    //create an interval that compute & displays elapsed time, as well as, animate red dot - every second
    elapsedTimeTimer = setInterval(() => {
        //compute the elapsed time every second
        let elapsedTime = computeElapsedTime(audioRecordStartTime); //pass the actual record start time
        //display the elapsed time
        displayElapsedTimeDuringAudioRecording(elapsedTime);
    }, 1000); //every second
}

/** Display elapsed time during audio recording
 * @param {String} elapsedTime - elapsed time in the format mm:ss or hh:mm:ss 
 */
function displayElapsedTimeDuringAudioRecording(elapsedTime) {
    //1. display the passed elapsed time as the elapsed time in the elapsedTime HTML element
    elapsedTimeTag.innerHTML = elapsedTime;

    //2. Stop the recording when the max number of hours is reached
    if (elapsedTimeReachedMaximumNumberOfHours(elapsedTime)) {
        stopAudioRecording();
    }
}

/**
 * @param {String} elapsedTime - elapsed time in the format mm:ss or hh:mm:ss  
 * @returns {Boolean} whether the elapsed time reached the maximum number of hours or not
 */
function elapsedTimeReachedMaximumNumberOfHours(elapsedTime) {
    //Split the elapsed time by the symbo :
    let elapsedTimeSplitted = elapsedTime.split(":");

    //Turn the maximum recording time in hours to a string and pad it with zero if less than 10
    let maximumRecordingTimeInHoursAsString = maximumRecordingTimeInHours < 10 ? "0" + maximumRecordingTimeInHours : maximumRecordingTimeInHours.toString();

    //if it the elapsed time reach hours and also reach the maximum recording time in hours return true
    if (elapsedTimeSplitted.length === 3 && elapsedTimeSplitted[0] === maximumRecordingTimeInHoursAsString)
        return true;
    else //otherwise, return false
        return false;
}

/** Computes the elapsedTime since the moment the function is called in the format mm:ss or hh:mm:ss
 * @param {String} startTime - start time to compute the elapsed time since
 * @returns {String} elapsed time in mm:ss format or hh:mm:ss format, if elapsed hours are 0.
 */
function computeElapsedTime(startTime) {
    //record end time
    let endTime = new Date();

    //time difference in ms
    let timeDiff = endTime - startTime;

    //convert time difference from ms to seconds
    timeDiff = timeDiff / 1000;

    //extract integer seconds that dont form a minute using %
    let seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff % 60); //ignoring uncomplete seconds (floor)

    //pad seconds with a zero if neccessary
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    //convert time difference from seconds to minutes using %
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

    //extract integer minutes that don't form an hour using %
    let minutes = timeDiff % 60; //no need to floor possible incomplete minutes, becase they've been handled as seconds
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

    //convert time difference from minutes to hours
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

    //extract integer hours that don't form a day using %
    let hours = timeDiff % 24; //no need to floor possible incomplete hours, becase they've been handled as seconds

    //convert time difference from hours to days
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24);

    // the rest of timeDiff is number of days
    let days = timeDiff; //add days to hours

    let totalHours = hours + (days * 24);
    totalHours = totalHours < 10 ? "0" + totalHours : totalHours;

    if (totalHours === "00") {
        return minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
        return totalHours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
}

// audio-recording.js ---------------
//API to handle audio recording 

var audioRecorder = {
    /** Stores the recorded audio as Blob objects of audio data as the recording continues*/
    audioBlobs: [],/*of type Blob[]*/
    /** Stores the reference of the MediaRecorder instance that handles the MediaStream when recording starts*/
    mediaRecorder: null, /*of type MediaRecorder*/
    /** Stores the reference to the stream currently capturing the audio*/
    streamBeingCaptured: null, /*of type MediaStream*/
    /** Start recording the audio 
     * @returns {Promise} - returns a promise that resolves if audio recording successfully started
     */
    start: function () {
        //Feature Detection
        if (!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)) {
            //Feature is not supported in browser
            //return a custom error
            return Promise.reject(new Error('mediaDevices API or getUserMedia method is not supported in this browser.'));
        }

        else {
            //Feature is supported in browser

            //create an audio stream
            return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }/*of type MediaStreamConstraints*/)
                //returns a promise that resolves to the audio stream
                .then(stream /*of type MediaStream*/ => {

                    //save the reference of the stream to be able to stop it when necessary
                    audioRecorder.streamBeingCaptured = stream;

                    //create a media recorder instance by passing that stream into the MediaRecorder constructor
                    audioRecorder.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream); /*the MediaRecorder interface of the MediaStream Recording
                    API provides functionality to easily record media*/

                    //clear previously saved audio Blobs, if any
                    audioRecorder.audioBlobs = [];

                    //add a dataavailable event listener in order to store the audio data Blobs when recording
                    audioRecorder.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
                        //store audio Blob object
                        audioRecorder.audioBlobs.push(event.data);
                    });

                    //start the recording by calling the start method on the media recorder
                    audioRecorder.mediaRecorder.start();
                });

            /* errors are not handled in the API because if its handled and the promise is chained, the .then after the catch will be executed*/
        }
    },
    /** Stop the started audio recording
     * @returns {Promise} - returns a promise that resolves to the audio as a blob file
     */
    stop: function () {
        //return a promise that would return the blob or URL of the recording
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            //save audio type to pass to set the Blob type
            let mimeType = audioRecorder.mediaRecorder.mimeType;

            //listen to the stop event in order to create & return a single Blob object
            audioRecorder.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                //create a single blob object, as we might have gathered a few Blob objects that needs to be joined as one
                let audioBlob = new Blob(audioRecorder.audioBlobs, { type: mimeType });
                
                //resolve promise with the single audio blob representing the recorded audio
                resolve(audioBlob);
            });
            audioRecorder.cancel();
        });
    },
    /** Cancel audio recording*/
    cancel: function () {
        //stop the recording feature
        audioRecorder.mediaRecorder.stop();

        //stop all the tracks on the active stream in order to stop the stream
        audioRecorder.stopStream();

        //reset API properties for next recording
        audioRecorder.resetRecordingProperties();
    },
    /** Stop all the tracks on the active stream in order to stop the stream and remove
     * the red flashing dot showing in the tab
     */
    stopStream: function () {
        //stopping the capturing request by stopping all the tracks on the active stream
        audioRecorder.streamBeingCaptured.getTracks() //get all tracks from the stream
            .forEach(track /*of type MediaStreamTrack*/ => track.stop()); //stop each one
    },
    /** Reset all the recording properties including the media recorder and stream being captured*/
    resetRecordingProperties: function () {
        audioRecorder.mediaRecorder = null;
        audioRecorder.streamBeingCaptured = null;

        /*No need to remove event listeners attached to mediaRecorder as
        If a DOM element which is removed is reference-free (no references pointing to it), the element itself is picked
        up by the garbage collector as well as any event handlers/listeners associated with it.
        getEventListeners(audioRecorder.mediaRecorder) will return an empty array of events.*/
    }
}
```

this is just a simple template that i want to use. but how can i deal with the model and viw and as well to the ajex to submit without refreshing the page
i want to create a model and a view to post the audio recorded –

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to create a model and a view to post the audio recorded